# Swift generic class with numeric and comparable protocols

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I want to write a swift generic class which takes numbers as the type which also conforming comparable protocol. Basically what I want is a generic `rangeValidator` which should take any kind of number (int, double, float) and returns whether it is inside the given range?

```
class NumberRangeValidator<T: Numeric,Comparable> {

    var minValue: T
    var maxValue: T

    init(minValue: T, maxValue: T) {
        self.minValue = minValue
        self.maxValue = maxValue
    }

    func validate(_ value: T) -> Bool {
       if case minValue...maxValue = value {
          return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: You don’t need to target numbers. You are seeking range functionality so all you need is for T to be comparable. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/closedrange

Comment: why not simply `0.0...1.0 ~= value`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your `class` is a "RangeValidator", I suggest making your class initializer take a `ClosedRange<T>`.  Declaring `T: Comparable` allows you to use `range.contains(value)` to do the validation:

**Note:** There is no need to restrict your class to `Numeric`, but if you want to then you can declare it as `class NumberRangeValidator<T: Comparable & Numeric>` as @JoakinDanielson mentioned in the comments.

```
class NumberRangeValidator<T: Comparable & Numeric> {

    let range: ClosedRange<T>

    init(range: ClosedRange<T>) {
        self.range = range
    }

    // allow range to be specified with minValue, maxValue
    init(minValue: T, maxValue: T) {
        guard minValue <= maxValue else { fatalError("Can't form Range with maxValue < minValue") }
        self.range = minValue...maxValue
    }

    func validate(_ value: T) -> Bool {
        return range.contains(value)
    }
}
```

**Examples:**

```
let validator = NumberRangeValidator(range: 10.0 ... 30.0)

print(validator.validate(9))   // false
print(validator.validate(10))  // true
print(validator.validate(20))  // true
print(validator.validate(30))  // true
print(validator.validate(31))  // false

let floatValidator = NumberRangeValidator(minValue: Float(0), maxValue: 5)
print(floatValidator.validate(0))   // true
print(floatValidator.validate(10))  // false
```

**Note:** There is no reason this needs to be a `class`.  A `struct` will do the job just as well.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that if OP wants to restrict the class to only numerics the declaration can be modified to `class NumberRangeValidator<T: Comparable & Numeric>`

Comment: Thanks @JoakimDanielson!  I added it to the answer.